# Screen goes completely black with white underscore

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

The problem appeared recently and I don't know how to pinpoint the cause of it. The screen will go completely black with a white underscore at the top left hand corner. This problem occurs a few times per hour.

The applications seem to still be running in the background, as I can still hear people and they can still see me if I am in a conference call. I can also login to another TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F{i}</kbd>, and if I restart the computer, it works just fine.

I'm running Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on my machine.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @ChanganAuto Lubuntu 18.04 is still supported here though until 2023.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).